# Magento Cron not working: no heartbeat task

Tags: magento, cron

I noticed the cron jobs not working because some tasks were not performed (automatic feed generation, google sitemap, ...).

1) I installed the (very useful) AOE scheduler

2) I've checked cron_schedule SQL table via PHPmyAdmin: no task is generated, but if I press Generate schedule in AOE scheduler, a list of task is generated. All tasks remain in pending status (executed at NULL).

3) I've set (crontab -e) 
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /home/fpl/webapps/magento/cron.sh

I've tried to run cron.sh manually via SSH. When I run manually the sh the heartbeat task is run. So I'm also sure the problem is not in the cron.sh script.

*Cron is properly running on the server.*

**Configuration**

Webfaction hosting
Magento ver. 1.8.0.0

Cron schedule Configuration on magento admin panel
Generate Schedules Every 1
Schedule Ahead for 20 
Missed if Not Run Within 15
Heartbeat task schedule (cron syntax) 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am having the exact same thing. Cron is running, but tasks stay on pending.

Comment: sorry, not yet found a solution

Comment: I've added this line: `$isShellDisabled = true;` (line: 49) before the `try` statement. After that put this line in your cron task:
`* * * * * php -q /home/<WEBSITE_NAME>/public_html/cron.php`

Answer (score 3):

my guess is that your `cron.sh` is not executable and that's why nothing is happening.
Please check the file persmission and add the executable flag

`chmod +x /home/fpl/webapps/magento/cron.sh`

You might also want to check your server's log files for cron (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log)

Instead of relying on the fact that cron is executable you could also run it like this

`/bin/bash /home/fpl/webapps/magento/cron.sh`

And: instead of writing down the minutes like that you should be using this:

`*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/fpl/webapps/magento/cron.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the status for crontab?

```
service crond status // depends on your OS
```

If its not running, start it

```
service crond start
```

And configure for system startup

```
chkconfig crond on
```

HTH

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but this is not the problem, crond (pid  21807) is running...

Comment: "service cron status" for some distributions

Answer (score 1):

edit cron.sh and change line 39 to:

```
PHP_BIN=`/usr/local/bin/php56`
```

It tries to use which php but that isn't so great on webfaction servers as there are lots of php versions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
crontab -e */5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.partsfortreadmill.com/cron.php
```

and setting a proper cron.php in the above path